# Textbox validation onfous using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build an Angular JS form. I'd like user to be able to set the focus on a text field when entering data in text field.
Thanks

Comment: show what you have done so far

Comment: View [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section to read about how to ask questions here on SO. For example you should at least show something you've tried your self. And perhaps be a bit more descriptive of what your problem actually is, currently it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want default autofocus to a particular text field then you can add a directive like below-

```
.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, $element) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $element[0].focus();
                }, 0);
            }
        };
    })
```

And use it with text box like -

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-focus

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="focus=true;blur=false;" ng-blur="blur=true;focus=false;"/>

<p>focus: {{focus}}</p>
<p>blur: {{blur}} </p>
```

if you want to set focus, or you can do like this

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="validate('somevalue')"/>
```

and

```
$scope.validate= function(text)
{
 // validate here
}
```